# ¿ Crear un array de diccionarios dinamicamente?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Necesito crear un array de diccionarios donde el tamaño de este array puede variar dinamicamente.

En este ejemplo creo un array de 10 elementos y solo relleno 2. Pero necesito que el array se vaya agrandando o empequeñeciendo según el código.

```
Dictionary<string, object>[] valor = new Dictionary<string, object>[10];
```

Para rellenarlo:

```
valor[0].Add("llave1","01");
valor[0].Add("llave2","02");
valor[1].Add("llave1","11");
valor[1].Add("llave2","12");
```

Si hiciéramos la equivalencia a un JSON la estructura podría ser como esta:

```
{  
   "informe":[{ "grupo1" : [{
                            "llave1": "01",
                            "llave2": "02"     
                            },
                            {
                            "llave1": "11",
                            "llave2": "12"
                            }]
                },
                { "grupo2" : [{
                            "llave1": "54",
                            "llave2": "62"     
                            },
                            {
                            "llave1": "35",
                            "llave2": "23"
                            }]
                 }]
 }
```

IMPORTANTE: Lo que necesito es declarar los elementos dinámicamente.

Comment: Por que no un `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` que es la estructura correcta si el tamaño es dinámico?

Comment: cuenta antes cuantas necesitas meter y lo haces como variable.

Comment: Eso si, creo que hay formas mejores, como lo que dice Pikoh

Comment: Si uso un List con un dictionary como lo hago para rellenarlo y vaciarlo ?

Comment: Como una lista de cualquier tipo. Alguien te pondrá ahora una respuesta :)

Comment: Hola, como dice Pikoh, una lista es mejor si no conoces el tamaño del array. Ella se irá ajustando dinámicamente aunque es algo más costoso en rendimiento, pero se notará a partir de una lista muy grande. 
Echa un vistazo y podrás ver el rendimiento y como utilizar las listas con los ejemplos: https://geeks.ms/jorge/2017/08/31/diferencias-de-rendimiento-entre-list-matrices-y-array-class-en-c/

Comment: Una colección de diccionarios no es una estructura de datos muy común... ¿puedes darnos un poco de contexto sobre el problema que intentas solucionar?

Comment: @Konamiman cada celda del array de diccionarios contiene una lista de claves para rellenar unos objetos. Digamos que seria algo asi como un JSON pero montado con diccionario

Comment: Como es la estructura del json ? porque quizas no es ningun diccionario el que debas usar. Edita la pregunta y explica cual es el objetivo que buscas

Comment: Voy a poner otro ejemplo..

Comment: @Popularfan cual sería el problema de usar un `Dictionary<int,Dictionary<string,object>>` en lugar de un array?

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal esa solucion que me planteas me gusta mas pero con un Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,object>> o quizas con el Dictionary<string, object> ya doy por supuesto que el 'objeto' puede ser otro Dictionary<string, object>. El caso es que necesito saber como podria trabajar con estas declaraciones para agregar elementos o borrar elementos

Comment: Dado tu problema, creo que la única alternativa que tenes es usar recursión para buscar/eliminar los nodos

Comment: Cual sería el criterio por el cual buscarías o eliminarías un registro?

Comment: Para agregar un nodo seria por ejemplo agregar a "informe",  "Grupo1" y a este el item que contiene (llave1 y llave2 ). Supongo que lo suyo seria usar directamente JSON con alguna libreria ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes utilizar lista, diccionarios y una clase que funcione de envoltorio.

Primero la clase que hara de envoltorio:

```
public class CustomWrap
{
    public List<Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>>> informe { get; set; }

    public CustomWrap()
    {
        informe = new List<Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>>>();
    }
}
```

Es una clase sumamente sencilla, solo tiene una propiedad que es `informe` y un constructor que inicializa dicha propiedad.

Ahora coloco como llenar o utilizar la clase `CustomWrap`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CustomWrap jsonObjTest = new CustomWrap();

    Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>> grupo1 = new Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>>();
    Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>> grupo2 = new Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>>();
    Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>> grupo3 = new Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>>();

    grupo1.Add("grupo1", new List<Dictionary<string, string>>());
    grupo1["grupo1"].Add(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "llave1", "01" }, { "llave2", "02" } });
    grupo1["grupo1"].Add(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "llave1", "11" }, { "llave2", "12" } });

    grupo2.Add("grupo2", new List<Dictionary<string, string>>());
    grupo2["grupo2"].Add(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "llave1", "54" }, { "llave2", "62" } });
    grupo2["grupo2"].Add(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "llave1", "35" }, { "llave2", "23" } });

    grupo3.Add("grupo3", new List<Dictionary<string, string>>());
    grupo3["grupo3"].Add(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "llave1", "54" }, { "llave2", "62" }, { "llave3", "100" } });
    grupo3["grupo3"].Add(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "llave1", "35" }, { "llave2", "23" }, { "llave3", "124" } });
    grupo3["grupo3"].Add(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "llave1", "35" }, { "llave2", "23" }, { "llave3", "634" } });

    jsonObjTest.informe.Add(grupo1);
    jsonObjTest.informe.Add(grupo2);
    jsonObjTest.informe.Add(grupo3);

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObjTest, Formatting.Indented);
}
```

El cual la salida o el valor de la variable `json` es:

```
{
  "informe": [
    {
      "grupo1": [
        {
          "llave1": "01",
          "llave2": "02"
        },
        {
          "llave1": "11",
          "llave2": "12"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "grupo2": [
        {
          "llave1": "54",
          "llave2": "62"
        },
        {
          "llave1": "35",
          "llave2": "23"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "grupo3": [
        {
          "llave1": "54",
          "llave2": "62",
          "llave3": "100"
        },
        {
          "llave1": "35",
          "llave2": "23",
          "llave3": "124"
        },
        {
          "llave1": "35",
          "llave2": "23",
          "llave3": "634"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Para cada grupo se crea un diccionario donde su valor sera una lista, Tambien resaltar que dentro de la clase `CustomWrap` puede crearte metodos para agregar grupos y llaves siempre validando las llaves agregadas a los diccionarios para que no se repitan y te salten excepciones.

El código que te dejo no quiere decir que sea la solución mas elegante, ya que se vuelve un poco tedioso y confuso ver diccionario dentro de listas y listas dentro de diccionario. Para darle un poquito mas de claridad (como coloque en el parrafo anterior), create tus propios metodos de agregar, eliminar y editar. Abajo dejo los enlace de la documentación de las lista y diccionarios donde podras encontrar mas infomación sobre como agregar y eliminar.

Algo mas que se puede identificar es que para cada grupo se crea un diccionario el cual solo contendra una llave con su valor, el cual para ***mi*** es desperdiciar el uso de un diccionario, aunque para el ejemplo funciona perfecto. Te aconsejo que si puedes cambiar la estructura del json a otra mucho mas simple, te facilitara el trabajo.

En el ejemplo utilizo `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` para obtener el json, esta libreria la puedes descargar desde el administrador de paquete de NuGet. Abajo dejo los enlace de la libreria.

> [List](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2): Representa una lista de objetos fuertemente tipados a la que se puede obtener acceso por índice.
>
> [Dictionary](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2): Representa una colección de claves y valores.
>
> [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/): Es una buena opción cuando el JSON que está leyendo o escribiendo se acerca a una clase .NET. [Documentación](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm).

Comment: grupo1, grupo2, grupo3 lo has declarado estáticamente y mi pregunta es como lo puedo crear dinámicamente?  ya que pueden haber x grupos

Comment: No estan de forma estatica, los he colocado quemados en el código. Pero la estructura que te deje es lo suficientemente elastica para agregar registro, en tu logica donde vas agregar los registro solo vas instanciando de la misma manera en que deje el ejemplo, solo que debes de utilizar variables las cuales contendran tu informacion a almacenar en CustomWrap.

Comment: ¿ Como declaras o instancias  grupo1, grupo2, grupo3 partiendo que al inicio de la ejecución  del programa no tienes ningún grupo y que puedes tener  n grupos ?

Comment: Al inicio de la ejecucion solo instancias a `CustomWrap` y a medidas que nesecitas ir creando grupo y llaves vas agregandolos. de algun lado debes de obtener los grupos y las llaves,  esa parte la adaptas a tu logica.

Comment: Los grupos los obtengo de una base de datos, webservice, etc...  pero como declaras dinámicamente esos grupos y llaves  ?

Comment: Una vez que obtengas esos datos los recorreres o procesas y vas agregandolo al customWrap. ya dependera de ti como vas extraer los grupos y las llaves y que nombre le daras. Pero cada vez que necesites agregar un grupo solo instancias un dictionario donde su valor es una lista de diccionarios.

Comment: Creo que tienes un problema de concepto, si te fijas las demas respuesta tambien utilizan listas con diccionarios ya que esos tipos de datos son los que se adaptan a lo que preguntas, En todas ellas hay llamadas al metodo `Add` el cual vas llamando cuando nesecites agregar informacion. Y si no es problema de concepto, entonces has formulado mal tu pregunta.

Comment: Imagina que de una base de datos me llegan 5 grupos... ¿ Como creo esos 5 grupos dinámicamente en código ? No puedo crearlos con for ( x = 0; x<5; x++ ) { Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>> x = new Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(); } . En mi pregunta ya pido que los diccionarios los quiero crear dinámicamente

Comment: Tú comentario apunta de que si tienes un problema de conceptos.

Comment: Alfinal volvi a revisar el código  uso la forma: Dictionary<string, object> informe = new Dictionary<string, object>(). De cada object vuelvo a declarar un Dictionary<string, object>() o un Dictionary<string, object>[] según convenga.

Answer (score 4):

Si usamos

http://json2csharp.com/

podras obtener la estructura c# para ese `json`, con lo cual no se necesita ningun `Dictionary<>`

```
public class Grupo1
{
    public string llave1 { get; set; }
    public string llave2 { get; set; }
}

public class Grupo2
{
    public string llave1 { get; set; }
    public string llave2 { get; set; }
}

public class Informe
{
    public List<Grupo1> grupo1 { get; set; }
    public List<Grupo2> grupo2 { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Informe> informe { get; set; }
}
```

Pero quizas el `Grupo1` y  `Grupo2` se podria definir simplemente como `Grupo`

La idea es que usando la libreria

[Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)

deserialices ese json a la clase usando

```
RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Recuerda que el json tiene estructura que debes respectar, no puedes aplicar propiedades como son las llaves como si fueran key de un diccionario, eso no funciona

Si vas a serializar un diccionario

[Serialize a Dictionary](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDictionary.htm)

podrias hacer que uno contenga al otro como ser

```
Dictionary<string, List<Grupo>> dic = new Dictionary<string, List<Grupo>>();

var grupo1 = new List<Grupo>() {
     new Grupo() { llave1 = "01", llave2 = "02"},
     new Grupo() { llave1 = "01", llave2 = "02"} 
  };

dic.Add("grupo1", grupo1);

var grupo2 = new List<Grupo>() {
     new Grupo() { llave1 = "xx", llave2 = "xx"}
  };

dic.Add("grupo2", grupo2);
```

Si quiere agregar algo adicional usarias

```
var lista = dic["grupo2"] as List<Grupo>;
lista.Add(new Grupo() { llave1 = "xx", llave2 = "xx"});
```

Comment: El problema es que lo debo crear dinamicamente porque puedo tener grupo1, grupo2, o grupo1, grupo2, grupo3..etc

Comment: edite la respuesta agregando algo que podria ayudar, adaptando el diccionario con listas para lograr una estructura como la del json

Answer (score 3):

Se me ocurre que crees un método para realizar el aumento o disminución, te dejo un ejemplo.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<string, object>[] valor = new Dictionary<string, object>[10];//Declaramos nuestra variable

    valor[0] = new Dictionary<string, object>();//inicializamos
    valor[0].Add("llave1", "01");//agregamos el dato
    valor[1] = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    valor[1].Add("llave2", "02");
    valor[2] = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    valor[2].Add("llave1", "11");
    valor[3] = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    valor[3].Add("llave2", "12");

    Resize(ref valor, 20);//llamamos al metodo que cambiara el tamaño, pasamos el parametro del diccionario y el valor.
}

public static void Resize(ref Dictionary<string, object>[] origen, int resize)//Método que realizara el cambio
{
    Dictionary<string, object>[] temp = new Dictionary<string, object>[resize];//creamos un diccionario temporal el cual llevara el nuevo tamaño
    int cont = 0;//inicializamos un contador
    foreach (var item in origen)//recorremos el diccionario de origen
    {
        temp[cont] = item;//llenamos los datos
        cont++;//incrementamos el contador
    }
    origen = null;//liberamos la memoria de la variable.
    origen = temp;//asignamos la nueva memoria de temp a origen.
}
```

Quizás no sea la forma más elegante, pero es lo que se me ocurrio en el momento.

De lo contrario utiliza

```
            List<Dictionary<string, object>> valor = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();//Lista dinámica
            Dictionary<string, object> item = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            item.Add("01", "01");
            valor.Add(item);//debes conocer el item que agregas y el que eliminas
            valor.Remove(item);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, pero esta solución no me sirve ya que no se los elementos que puedo tener, pueden ser 10, 15, o 100